# VBA Compile Error: "Expected: end of statement" - (Working between different sheets)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that consists of two Sheets. I have written the following code in order to copy and sort the unique values of H column in Sheet 1 to Sheet 2, starting from A3.

```
Sub SortUniqueValues1()

Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant

j = Application.Transpose Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("H2", .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each i In j
        .Item(i) = i
    Next
 Cells(3, 1).Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
End With

End Sub
```

I keep on getting the "expected: end of statement error". I believe that it has to do something with this part:

```
j = Application.Transpose Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("H2", .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying

```
j = Application.Transpose Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("H2", .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))
```

to:

```
With Sheets("Sheet 1")
    j = Application.Transpose(.Range("H2", .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))
End With
```

**Also**, are you sure your sheet's name is "Sheet 1" and not "Sheet1" ?

Comment: @meletkis on that line ? Strange, since I ran this code without an error

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I miss-typed something. It works flawlessly!

Comment: I forgot to add the sort part `Range("A3:M10000").Sort Key1:=Range("A3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo` Any ideas how can I turn "A3:M10000" to "A3:M" Thank you

Comment: @meletkis `"A3:M" & LastRow` where `LastRow` is a variable equals to your last row wit data

Comment: So, how is the code going to be? I am confused. Thank you!

Comment: @meletkis sound like a great new **SO** post

Comment: Here you are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739865/vba-sort-unique-values-under-if-conditions-working-between-different-sheets