# Sort unique values under IF conditions (Working between different sheets)

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, if-statement

I have a workbook with the following two Sheets. In Sheet1 there is the data.

```
| Order |     Date | Status | 
|-------|---------:|-------:|
| 78    | 19-04-19 | OK     | 
| 33    | 19-04-19 | OK     | 
| 198   | 19-04-19 | CL     | 
| 43    | 19-04-19 | CL     | 
| 29    | 19-04-19 | CL     | 
| 12    | 20-04-19 | CL     | 
| 169   | 20-04-19 | OK     | 
| 95    | 20-04-19 | OK     | 
| 54    | 20-04-19 | OK     | 
| 31    | 20-04-19 | OK     |
```

What I am trying to achieve is to sort 'Order' unique values under the condition that Status=OK. So far, with a bit of help I have managed to write the code for the case that there is no condition. I tried to integrate the condition below but I keep on getting errors.

```
Sub SortUniqueValues2()

Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant

With Sheets("Sheet1")
LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In .Range("P2:P" & LRow)
If cell.Value = "OK" Then
j = Application.Transpose(.Range("H2", .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))

End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each i In j
            .Item(i) = i
        Next
     Cells(3, 21).Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
    End With

End If

Range("T3:AF100000").Sort Key1:=Range("T3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
| Order |
|-------|
| 31    |
| 33    |
| 54    |
| 78    |
| 95    |
| 169   |
```

I am trying to find out the following:

1. How can I integrate into the code the Status Condition?
2. Is there any way to create some sort of dropdown menu that will turn on/off conditions?
3. How can I convert A3:M100000 to A3 until the last value in column M?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Surely that can't be your code? If has mismatched `if/end if`, missing `next`, stray `end with`, it won't compile.

Comment: @GSerg I know it doesn't work. The question is how I make this work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by "*working between different sheets*". In your question and your code, I only see a reference to a single sheet.

But there are built-in functions that can do most of what you want:

- Copy to the results sheet to leave the source data unchanged
- `RemoveDuplicates`
- `Sort`
- `AutoFilter`

I'm not sure what you want so far as a "dropdown", but if you set up an autofilter, you can use the arrow key to filter on the status.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub sortUniqueOK()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, R As Range

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet4")

'Get the source data range
'Modify to your data location (Cells(1,1) = A1) for the upper left cell
With wsSrc
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
End With

'Copy to a results worksheet
With wsRes
    .Cells.Clear
    R.Copy .Cells(1, 1)

    'set R to the range on the new worksheet
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
End With

'Remove Duplicates
R.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes

'Sort
With wsRes.Sort.SortFields
    .Clear
    .Add Key:=R(columnindex:=3), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending
    .Add Key:=R(columnindex:=1)
End With

With wsRes.Sort
    .SetRange R
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'To just show the `OK` status features, you can use an autofilter
R.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="OK"

End Sub
```

You can also accomplish the same results using Power Query

Comment: Thank you very much! I have recently started to look into VBA and that was really helpful!